# CORS Issue Even After Adding CORS package

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have added CORS package in WebApi code

Also have added `config.EnableCors();` in `WebApiConfig.Register`

But while calling Api from different url , getting below error -

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:52016/api/values/' from
> origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also add the following attribute to your controllers:

```
[EnableCors(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*"]
```

You can read more about this attribute and it's properties here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#:~:text=The%20origins%20parameter%20of%20the,list%20of%20the%20allowed%20origins.&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20the,allowing%20requests%20from%20any%20origin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#:%7E:text=The%20origins%20parameter%20of%20the,list%20of%20the%20allowed%20origins.&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20the,allowing%20requests%20from%20any%20origin).